# Rotate on key down, revert rotate on key up?

Tags: c#, unity

How would I rotate an object a certain number of degrees when the left arrow is pressed and then rotate it back to its start when the left arrow is released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) and [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html). Unity makes it really easy.

The [scripting reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/index.html) is your best friend.

Something like the following:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 30, 0);
else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
```